# Don't have the option to use carrier billing

Tags: google-play-store

I erased off my phone the carrier billing payment from Google play store how can I get it back so I can buy games,I totally don't know how I did it

Comment: Look up the name of your carrier on google play. See what applications are listed there. Install them if they're not already on there. Update your registration info on them.